# How to display only day and month in SharePoint list column?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have a column named `Birthday` and a field on it would be: `04/11/1998`; How can I create a calculated column namd `BirthGET` that contains only day and month, i.e `04/11`.

How can I make this?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use an index counter as mentioned by Amal...

Here is what I would use `=TEXT([Birthday],"mm/dd")` This is a more well rounded solution which will allow you to do more.

This will give you exactly what you are looking for. Both methods will work for you but this will give you exactly what you want if the date is oriented if displayed worded or in number format. You can also transpose the date into worded date format by using `mmmm, dd yyyy`

Comment: it is working nice

Answer (score 3):

You can use below formula

```
=LEFT(BirthDay, 5)
```

Comment: this is not working it is generating unknown number for me!